# Как заполнить диагонали в двумерном массиве?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Как в JavaScript заполнить двухмерный массив так как показано на рисунке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример кода (без реализации):

```
var arr = [];
var size = 7;
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    arr[i] = [];
}
for (var i = 0; i <size; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        arr[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: вы что-то уже смогли набросать или хотите готовое решение?

Comment: заполнить циклом

Comment: а как его заполнить циклом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let arr = [];
const rows = 7,
  cols = 7;

for(let i = 0; i < rows; i++){
  arr[i] = [];
  for(let j = 0; j < cols; j++){
    arr[i][j] = i === j || i === cols - j - 1 ? 1 : 0;
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Большое вам СПАСИБО!!!